# Kafka Streams transform() state store

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a use case where I need to use headers in DSL so used transformValues() but not doing stateful transformation , more of decision making based on headers.
I need to pass the state store name in this function.Is there any alternative of not giving a state store of some default or dummy value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to pass the state store name in this function

That is not correct. The signature of `KStream#transformValues()` is

```java
<VR> KStream<K, VR> transformValues(final ValueTransformerSupplier<? super V, ? extends VR> valueTransformerSupplier,
                                    final String... stateStoreNames);
```

Note, that the second argument is a var-arg, and you don't need to provide any parameter for it. Hence, you can call `transformValue()` with a single argument.